# Angular Nested Class

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, typescript, class

i'm new in angular, but i want to asking is there way to create nested class in angular like this .net class?

```
public class BaseResponse<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public BaseResponse()
    {

    }

    public BaseResponse(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public BaseResponse(int statusCode, string message)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Message = message;
    }

    public BaseResponse(T data, int statusCode, string message)
    {
        Data = data;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

When i'm using this class and add class to T object, example **Section** class, here's the result from Backend:

```
{
"Data": [
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "SectionName": "Section3",
        "Description": "Description3"
    },
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "SectionName": "Section4",
        "Description": "Description4"
    }
],
"StatusCode": 200,
"Message": "Data successfully retrieved"
}
```

How to access this JSON data from angular?
I try this below code but failed.

```
export class Baseresponse<T> {
    Data:T;
    StatusCode:number;
    Message:string;

    constructor(data:T,statuscode:number,message:string) {
        this.Data=data;
        this.StatusCode=statuscode;
        this.Message=message;
    }
}
```

this is my service but nothing work

```
export class SectionService {
objectResponse:Baseresponse<Section>;
 
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

getAllSection(){
  this.http.get(environment.wsURL+'/SectionGetAll').toPromise().then(res=>this.objectResponse=res);
  return this.objectResponse;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of asynchronous approach. When you call `this.http.get` it will be queued and `return this.objectResponse` returns undefined for that moment. You need to do smth like this:

```js
export class SectionService {
  objectResponse: Baseresponse<Section>;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllSection(): Promise<Baseresponse<Section>> {
    /* 
      we return Promise object to have ability handle 
      the request or error in a place where we are going to call it 
    */

    return this.http
      .get(environment.wsURL + '/SectionGetAll')
      .toPromise();

    /* 
      if you need a simple cache you can: 

      if (this.objectResponse) { 
        return Promise.resolve(this.objectResponse);
      }

      return this.http
        .get(environment.wsURL + '/SectionGetAll')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => this.objectResponse = response);
    */
  }
}
```

Then somewhere in a component or another service:

```js
export class SomeClass {
  /* inject appropriate service */
  constructor(private sectionService: SectionService) {}

  getAll() {
    /* fetch all sections and handle the request */
    this.sectionService.getAllSection()
      .then(response => /* handle response */)
  }
}
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise